# Substraction between 2 tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am doing a webshop for my studies, it's done but I would like to make it extra good for better mark by doing this join stuff, but I don't understand how this works. I tried inner join but that confused me more.

I have 2 tables that looks like this:

prices:

```
id | name | price  | raktaron   
1  | why  | 9000   | 20
```

raktaron means 'in stock'

superuser_cart:

```
id | item             | quantity | value  | name        |date   
1  | whytshirt - L    | 2        | 18000  | why         |2021-09-17 09:11:02
```

At the checkout I want to substract the cart.quantity from the prices.raktaron

Something like this:

```
 UPDATE prices 
    SET raktaron = raktaron-superuser_cart.quantity 
WHERE name = superuser_cart.name;
```

Comment: It's probably not a good idea basing the link on the name - you should be using the prices.ID field in your cart table. Makes no difference to this issue, but it's probably not a good database design - you may run into duplicate names, or you might want to change a name. Just wanting to display the name in the cart isn't a good reason - that's what a JOIN is for.

Comment: Might it be something like `update prices set raktaron = raktaron - (select quantity from superuser_cart where prices.name = superuser_cart.name)` ? I don't have anything set up to try it. You may also need to look at doing a transaction which will update the prices.raktaron at the same time as removing the line from superuser_cart, so it doesn't get processed more than once. Will you ever have more than one cart active at a time?

Comment: *WHERE name = superuser_cart.name* The values for `name` are not equal in shown data example - no update will be performed even when you'll fix the syntax error.

Comment: Provide show create table for both of your tables. based on your table design the `name` column should be unique in both of your table, or your `superuser_cart id` should be only  related to the `id` in the `prices` table

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
UPDATE prices 
Inner JOIN superuser_cart ON prices.name = superuser_cart.name
SET prices.raktaron = prices.raktaron - superuser_cart.quantity;
select * from prices;
```

or with specify "name"

```
UPDATE prices 
INNER JOIN superuser_cart ON prices.name = superuser_cart.name
SET prices.raktaron = prices.raktaron - superuser_cart.quantity
WHERE prices.name = "some thing";
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` usage is an error. This query will "kill" (set to NULL) the value in all rows of `prices` which have no matched row in `superuser_cart` ([model](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d5ae7654d541ea8cdd800a55f2bf2a69)). INNER JOIN must be used.

Comment: thank you @Akina i changed my answer it work with where clause.

Comment: Your WHERE in 2nd query does not guarantee that matched row in `superuser_cart` exists, so it does not fix possible problem. INNER JOIN must be used in this case strictly.

Answer (score 0):

As other pointed out in the comments it is not a good idea to update based on the `name` except if the `name` is unique in both tables.

If you have more data examples and provide table description for both tables, maybe there will be another ***better*** solution.

Based on your data, below query works ***but if you have two `why` values in your `name` column on `superuser_cart` table it will not***.

```
update  prices p 
inner join superuser_cart s
on p.name=s.name 
set p.raktaron=p.raktaron-( select quantity 
                                   from superuser_cart 
                                    where name ='why') ;
```

Demo of not working:https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/30

Demo based on your data: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/29